# CSS white-space:pre always renders a horizontal scrollbar in firefox

Tags: css, firefox, scrollbar, whitespace

**EDIT:** *This issue is no longer present in the latest Firefox version!*

So I have a **table with 100% width** in a **div with a max-width of 800px**, I don't want to wrap the content of the table, so I use:

```
white-space: nowrap;
```

The problem is, **I get a horizontal scroll bar**, even if the content is not 800px. Do you guys know why? I'd like to have no wrap, and no horizontal scroll up to a certain width.

And this is only in Firefox, **in Chrome it works fine**.

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p4zab0fa/3/) to show the problem.

Comment: I don't see a scrollbar, except when the browser window itself is under 800px.

Comment: You don't see a scrollbar in firefox? I do! In chrome it works fine

Comment: @MrLister Thanks for answering. "The #definitionDiv is always the same width as the table inside...." not sure, in Firefox, if you look closely, the last table, is larger than the first 2! In Chrome it is not. Unfortunately, the div needs to be positioned absolutely, overflow visible for both y, x is not good because these tables can get pretty big vertically (I'd love for overflow-x: visible to work, but it doesn't). Hmm setting the width manually solved it! I'd accept that as an answer, since it seems there is no clear css solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks to be a bug in Firefox. (The same problem is in the latest nightly build, so it'll be here for a while.) And there doesn't seem to be a solution, only workarounds.

The problem is that, if the container is positioned absolutely, the procedure with Gecko appears to be as follows:

- The absolutely positioned container only needs to be as wide as its contents
- So if the contents are, e.g. 300px wide, then the container will be 300px wide too
- If the contents are higher than the container, add a vertical scrollbar
- But don't adjust the container's width to account for this scrollbar
- So now the contents are wider than the container's viewport.

Example:

```css
#definitionDiv {
  position: absolute;
  left: 20px;
  top: 20px;
  max-height: 150px;
  overflow: auto;
}
.data {
  width: 220px;
  height: 220px;
  border: 40px inset #CCB;
  background: #CCB;
}
```

```html
<div id="definitionDiv">
   <div id="definitionDivContent">
    <div class="data">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Well then. Possible workarounds are: don't position the `#definitionDiv` absolutely. Or, use JavaScript to calculate what the width of the contents is, and adjust the `#definitionDiv` accordingly. Or, set a fixed width that you know is large enough. Or, `overflow:visible`.

The most elegant solution I found so far is to adjust the width of the contents by giving it a right margin as wide as the scrollbar. Then you won't have to work out what the max width of the widest table will be.

```css
#definitionDiv {
  position: absolute;
  left: 20px;
  top: 20px;
  max-height: 150px;
  overflow: auto;
}
#definitionDiv > :first-child {
  margin-right: 25px;
}
.data {
  width: 220px;
  height: 220px;
  border: 40px inset #CCB;
  background: #CCB;
}
```

```html
<div id="definitionDiv">
  <div id="definitionDivContent">
    <div class="data">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem, of course, is that the other browsers will then put the scrollbar more to the right than Firefox. I haven't been able to come up with a solution for that one.

Comment: I believe it has been fixed in the latest Firefox, so now it works fine in both Chrome and Firefox

Comment: @dalvarezmartinez1 I still see the same differences, using the newest nightly/Canary browsers.

Comment: Canary browsers? You mean Chrome? That is strange, since it was not possible for me to reproduce it in Chrome in the first place. And now it's not possible to reproduce it in Firefox either...

Comment: I see [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AU5EM.png) in the latest browsers (for the top snippet). Only Firefox has the horizontal scrollbar, same as before. So nothing has changed for me. However, when I get home, I can check in different OSes (Linux, etc).